# child div's size should not increase but only decrease in size relative to the parent div

Tags: html, css

how can I design a child div whose initial size should not increase with the expansion of the parent div but should only shrink when the parent div decreases in size.
And the div should always be a square.

I am trying to use min-width and min-height but it doesn't work.

```
#parentDiv{
      position:relative;
      border:solid pink;
 }

#childDiv{
      position:absolute;
      right:10px;
      bottom:10px;
      width:250px;
      height:250px;
      min-width:2%;
      min-height:2%;
      border:solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Set a 'max-width: XYZpx` and then set the width to x%.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the width and height in % so that they're proportional to the parent's sizing, and set a max-height and max-width to whatever you want the maximum size to be.

so:

```
width: 20%;
height: 20%; //will make sure div is always 20% of parent's height 
max-width: 250px;
max-height: 250px; //will never go bigger than 250px
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply do something like this:  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g79TJ/)

```
#parent {
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#child {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS-only solution that assumes that the square has an explicitly defined maximum width.  This means that whenever the user loads the page and decides to reduce the browser width, the child div may not start reducing right away.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

body > div {
    height: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}

div > div {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 100px;
}

div > div:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

And, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8e89/.

The following is a JavaScript solution.  The maximum width of the child div is not defined.  Instead, the initial width is remembered by the JS program when the page loads.  If the user decides to reduces the viewport size, this time, the child div will start reducing right away.

Same HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Slightly different CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

body > div {
    height: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}

div > div {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    width: 20%;
}

div > div:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

And, JS/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var win = $(window).eq(0),
        initialWinWidth = win.outerWidth(),
        $squareDiv = $("div > div").eq(0),
        squareDivWidth = $squareDiv.outerWidth(),
        ratio = squareDivWidth / initialWinWidth;

    $(window).resize(function(evt) {
        var winWidth = win.outerWidth();
        $squareDiv.css("width", winWidth > initialWinWidth ? squareDivWidth : winWidth * ratio);
    });
});
```

And, a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy5ah/.